# iOS - Custom view not filling superview

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I've made a navigationbar for my app, that I would like to reuse in all of my screens.

The problem is however that it doesn't fill the assigned space.
So, how can I set that the custom navigationbar view should have the same width and height as the superview it's assigned?

My NavigationBarView.swift:

```
import UIKit

class NavigationBarView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NavigationBarView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }
}
```

Which loads my NavigationBarView.xib.

And then on my Main.storyboard I've created a new view and set the class for the view to "NavigationBarView". But now it's only filling around half of the assigned space.

How can I get it to fill the entire space?

Comment: Assign the value of NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NavigationBarView", owner: self, options: nil) to a variable.

Comment: Have you used constraints to make it fill the space?

Comment: I've set constraints to make the superview align properly.. I don't know where to set the constraints to make it fill the space?

Answer (score 0):

> you have to give flash screen fist if it is not working then call below method

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // set your custom view frame here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I understand..
How should I set the custom view frame?

Comment: navigationBar.farme = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame

Comment: if you are using auto layout then set top and trailing leading  constraints'

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/bwhiteley/049e4bede49e71a6d2e2

```
class CustomView : UIView {
@IBOutlet weak private var contentView:UIView!
// other outlets

override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonInit()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth
    self.addSubview(contentView)
}
}
```

It works like a charm. :-)